# Can't find node-gyp

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, msgpack

- Windows 7
- node 6.9
- npm 3.10.8
- python 2.7
- node-gyp 3.6.2
- VS Build tools 2015

---

When installing `msgpack`, I'm getting this error:

[image]

I've already set `npm_config_node_gyp` as env var with `C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js` as value.

My `node-gyp` command works fine.

What am I missing? The `msbuild` is not even called.

I tried installing in another computer (a Win10 one), worked fine...

Comment: hello, I just wanted to suggest a working solution for your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037228/find-path-with-unsorted-data#46037228. But it was deleted. Feel free to undelete if you still need it. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I will undelete the question! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

some of nodejs tools need developer tools and confiration to work on microsoft windows. Follow this link here is mentioned step wise:

> https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

Comment: I have everything configured exactly as this link asks, including this one: https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md