# Find path with unsorted data

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have this data:

```
data = [
    {"start": "MIA", "end": "FCA"},
    {"start": "FCA", "end": "GVK"},
    {"start": "GVK", "end": "LSD"}
]
```

With this data, I need to find a path. In the above case, the path would be  from `MIA` to `FCA`, then `FCA` to `GVK` and, finally, `GVK` to `LSD`. The path will never have branches and It never goes back to a point that It has already passed, no loops. As output, I just need to get the `"end"` point of each element of the `data` array: `["FCA", "GVK", "LSD"]`

So, that's what I've tried:

```
def find_path(connections, counter, data):
    if connections[-1] == data[counter]["start"]:
        connections.append(data[counter]["end"])
        if len(connections) == len(data):
            return connections
    return find_path(connections, counter+1, data)
```

It works only because the `data` is sorted. But when I change `data` just like this:

```
data = [
    {"start": "FCA", "end": "GVK"},
    {"start": "MIA", "end": "FCA"},
    {"start": "GVK", "end": "LSD"}
]
```

It fails.

**QUESTION:** What would be a neat way to achieve this?

I thought about resetting the `counter` in the top of the function when it reaches the end of the data: `counter = 0 if counter == len(data) else counter`, but with this, I would have to discount at `connections` index here: `if connections[-1] == data[counter]["start"]:` and append `data` element in a different position here: `connections.append(data[counter]["end"])`. I think It's getting a little bit messy.

Comment: 1. Build a graph. 2. Use a standard graph search algorithm. For further reading: https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/

Comment: Oh nice. I didn't realized that would be a graph problem. I'll try this one: https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/ . Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following recursive function will do the job:

```
data = [
    {"start": "FCA", "end": "GVK"},
    {"start": "MIA", "end": "FCA"},
    {"start": "GVK", "end": "LSD"}
]

def find_path(data, start='', result=[]):
    l = data.copy()
    for d in data:
        if d['start'] == start:
            result.append(d['end'])
            l.remove(d)
            find_path(l, result[-1], result)
    return result

print(find_path(data, 'MIA'))
```

The output:

```
['FCA', 'GVK', 'LSD']
```